# Why isn't OnCollisionEnter2D working?

Tags: unity, c#

I've made a hole. I have animals tagged as animals. When an animal walks into the hole, they disappear. I tried `OnTriggerEnter2D()` as well, and set the collider to `isTrigger`, but it still didn't work. I can get it to work without the tag part, but anything that bumps into each other sets each other to inactive.

```
public class BlackHole : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "animal")
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your animal object have children objects with colliders? If so you need to make sure their tag is also set to "animal".

Comment: @Infodayne, this sounded incorrect, so I tested it. Child game object tags do not conflict with the direct game object, when you check its tag.

Comment: @Gnemlock Yes, but perhaps his root animal gameobject is simply a container/parent. If this root gameobject has the correct tag, but no collider, then the tag of the children nodes need to be set to "animal".

Answer (score 1):

The fact that this *works*, but *only* if you omit the tag statement, implies that the only possible cause derives from your tagging. You must ensure that the required game objects have the *exact* same tag; in this case, `animal`. Tags are case sensitive, so a game object tagged as "Animal" will not return `true` if you check for a tag of "animal".

[image: The game object must list the required tag as it's "tag", under it's name.]

As a final note, when we create custom tags, they do not automatically apply to a game object - even if we have been directed to the custom tags screen through the tag selection for that game object. It is fairly easy to forget this, but we *must* actually set the tag to the game object, after creating it.

Comment: Don't forget to note that `CompareTag("foo")` is generally to be preferred over `.tag == "foo"`. One requires pulling a string from unmanaged code into managed code (allocations) and the other doesn't. ;) ([See this thread for details](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/200820/is-comparetag-better-than-gameobjecttag-performanc.html))